# How do I find Wronskian for $y(t) = (c_1, tc_2, t^2c_3)e^{at}$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

If I try to use the formula it becomes very difficult to compute:
$$y'(t) = ac_1e^{at} + atc_2e^{at}+ c_2e^{at} + at^2c_3e^{at} + 2tc_3e^{at}$$
and then continue with $y''$ and use the formula it becomes very complicated. Is there an easier way of doing this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

From the solution:
$$y(t) = (c_1, tc_2, t^2c_3)e^{at}$$
you can deduce the characteristic polynomial:
$$(r-a)^3=0$$
$$r^3-3ar^2+3a^2r-a^3=0$$
Then you can deduce the differential equation:
$$y'''-3ay''+3a^2y'-a^3y=0$$
$$y'''+p_1y''+p_2y'+p_3y=0$$
Then you can deduce the Wronskian using [Abel's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_identity).
$$W=c \exp \left (-\int p_1(t)dt \right)$$
Here $p_1=-3a$.
$$W(t)=ce^{3at}$$

Comment: How do I find here ?

Comment: @Ashh3720  $P_1$ is the coefficent of $y''$ and $W(t)=ce^{3at}$

Comment: sorry i meant how do I find c @user577215664

Comment: Normally we leave it this way but if you need the wronskian with the constant then you have to calculate the determinant @Ashh3720